# Fastest way to update database table

Tags: sql, query-performance, vertica

I have a table with around 100 million rows of data. I need to update some columns of this table (around 50) based on some values from another table. 
It has only one primary key column. No other constraints.

something like this

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

I need the processing to be done in minutes.
Does normal databases serve the purpose or should I go for in memory databases.

Is there any approach better than this single update statement?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on where you have indexes on your table. The more indexes you have defined on the columns you are updating the slower your update will perform. Balace this with the indexes you need for joining the 2 tables and your where clause for the select statement. Still... 30 minutes to update 50 records sounds heavy

Comment: I have only one primary key and no indexes created.

Comment: 50 records, or 50 columns affecting 100M records?

Comment: Its 50 Columns that might get effected

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very interesting use case for the Vertica *flattened table* approach.

I suggest you read the Vertica documentation on it.

Suffice to say that you could:

```
ALTER TRABLE table_a ALTER COLUMN col1 
DEFAULT (SELECT col1 FROM table_b WHERE table_b.id=table_a.id);
```

(or, if that column already contains data, first drop it, then re-add it with that default).

I have obtained quite some nice performance results. Worth a try, I think ....